# Box-box contact information

Tags: 3d, mathematics, physics, xna-4.0

I have two colliding boxes, How i can calculate contact information like (contact normal, contact point and penetration) .

Is there any simple algorithm .

Note: i'm using XNA .

Comment: what is this you should enter more information

Comment: Are you using a physics engine, or creating your own implementation?

Comment: I'm building physics engine

Comment: The only reason to make a physics engine from scratch is because you interested in the math. If that is the case buy a physics gaming book and have fun. Else I suggest trying something that already exists http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Are the two boxes axis aligned (ie - the borders are aligned to the x and y axis?), or can they be on an angle (ie, defined by four arbitrary points?)?

Comment: @ClassicThunder I build it for my University, So i must build it but not form scratch, If i want, I can use some algorithm. Thank you for link :) .

Comment: @lochok I have both cases :( .

Comment: Google OBB (Oriented bounding boxes) algorithms if your boxes are arbitrarily aligned otherwise you can use AABB (Axis-aligned bounding boxes) algorithms. Also for extensive detail and algorithms I recommend the book "Real Time Collision Detection" by Christer Ericson.

Answer (score 1):

I think this topic has been discussed a few times in the "Physics for Game Programmers" tutorial sessions at the Game Developers Conference.

This paper should at least give you some ideas: [Contact Generation by Erwin Coumans](http://web.archive.org/web/20160101163908/https://bullet.googlecode.com/files/GDC10_Coumans_Erwin_Contact.pdf).

There has definitely been at least one presentation by Erin Catto about how he does it in Box2d, but it's not clear whether the OP wants 2d or 3d. Anyway, his presentations are excellent and at least one of them (the 2008 one IIRC) mentions contact generation between two boxes via clipping: http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding your question, but if you're looking for general info on collision detection Microsoft has two MSDN pages available, one specifically for XNA:

[Bounding Volumes and Collisions in XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313876.aspx)

[Collision Detection Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb313876%28v=xnagamestudio.20%29.aspx)

You could also look at the Box2D physics engine to get more detailed info on the technical aspects.

Comment: I think it's just for Collision Detection and it does not return any collision information